# RuntimeError: Declare either attr_protected or attr_accessible for User, but not both

Tags: ruby-on-rails, unit-testing, restful-authentication

Since a short time my rails applications yields the following runtime error in the test suite:

```
RuntimeError: Declare either attr_protected or attr_accessible for User, but not both.
```

This was probably introduced by an update to restful_authentication. But scanning the code for "attr_protected" only shows me it is never called. So why this error message?

My user model only has the following code:

```
attr_accessible :login, :email, :name, :password, :password_confirmation, :identity_url
```

So it should be perfectly okay? Any clues where to look for the problem? Searching google shows a few clueless people who also see this problem only in test environment and sporadically in the development environment.

Comment: Have you added any other plugins recently? I do not think this is an issue with restful_authentication, but maybe some other piece of code which has been included recently.

Comment: Make sure to grep for `protected_attributes` as well, as that is the class accessor they are stored under, and you will get this error if `User.protected_attributes` is not nil. What kind of test framework are you using, maybe it is a problem with a mock of User? Does this happen during unit tests, functionals, or both?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If you are using RestfulAuthentication with friendly_id, the latest version of friendly_id can bring this error as indicated on the github page:

> Also, this feature uses attr_protected to protect the cached_slug column, unless you have already invoked attr_accessible. So if you wish to use attr_accessible, you must invoke it BEFORE you invoke has_friendly_id in your class.
>   [github page](http://github.com/norman/friendly_id)

Also, when using grep to find occurences of keywords, don't forget to grep also in gems as you may have installed some plugins as gem archive.

Answer (score 0):

<strike>You might have `include`d modules into the `User` class that declare `attr_protected`.  Maybe some kind of testing functionality does that.</strike>

Comment: I grepped the whole source tree for "attr_protected" - nothing there (at least nowhere related to the user model).

Answer (score 0):

This could be due to a plugin adding `attr_protected`. [This](http://timothynjones.wordpress.com/2008/08/02/acts_as_audited-and-declare-either-attr_protected-or-attr_accessible-for-user-but-not-both/) might be helpful.

Comment: Indeed a plugin added attr_protected to my User model (it was RestfulAuthentication itself as far as I traced it but I'm not going to look into that further as I'm going to dump RA in favor of AuthLogic).